# Position ticks in react-chartjs-2

Tags: react-chartjs-2

Is there a way to position the ticks? I can't seem to find documentation on this. I'm creating an horizontal bar chart and I need the ticks to be above the respective bars like this.

[image]

```
const options = {
elements: {
  bar: {
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
},
indexAxis: 'y' as const,
plugins: {
  datalabels: {
    display: false,
  },
  legend: {
    labels: {
      usePointStyle: true,
      boxHeight: 8,
      boxWidth: 8,
    },
    display: true,
  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Test',
  },
},
responsive: true,
scales: {
  x: {
    stacked: true,
  },
  y: {
    stacked: true,
    barThickness: 20,
    ticks: {
      color: '#000',
      fontStyle: 'bold',
      stepSize: 1,
      mirror: true,
    },
  },
},
```

};